# Remove remote branch and push local

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

As you see below, I reverted a commit in local repository and commited but not pushed 2 other changes. But the remote repository still has the commit I reverted. So how can I make the remote repository exactly the local one? (I want to remove that purple branch and push 2 local commits)

[image]

The repository is personal, no risk of somebody gets out of sync.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I am a noob at git, so it would be great if you explain your answers clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to "delete" a part of history, you have to "force" your push.

But instead of use `git push --force`, you'd better use `git push --force-with-lease`.

The last command checks whether anyone didn't pushed after the commits you want to destroy.
In the case, the push is rejected, avoiding losing your friend's commit(s).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by following command on console:

```
git push -f
```

And it basically removed the commit i wanted to remove from remote repository and pushed my local commits.